# Writing and integrating a batch file to create directory listing

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to modify the Windows 7 "Print Directory Listing" option to allow me to create a simple text list of the files located in the folder, saved to that folder. A couple of hours of Googling only found "Print Directory Listing" directions.

I've tried a few attempts at modifying the PRINTDIR.BAT file, but I'm pretty sure my output directory selection is wrong.

Here's my current effort, pared down to the bare metal.

```
@echo off  
dir %1 > ".\_Listing.txt"  
exit
```

The batch file is saved into the C:\Windows\ folder, and I suspect it's attempting to create the file in and of that folder, instead of the desired target folder.

Comment: What do you intend with the parameter (`%1`)? Should it be a filemask or the directory to be listed?

Comment: `dir %1 > "%~1\_Listing.txt"` should place the `_Listing.txt` file within listed directory; that `~` modifier in `%~1` expands `%1` removing any surrounding `"` double quotes

Comment: Are you wanting to double click on PRINTDIR.BAT and have it run? How do you intend to get the %1 parameter set?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, and thanks for the advice. My goal is to integrate the .bat file folder alt-menu. I'd like to right-click on a folder, and generate a listing of the contents of the selected folder, inside the folder, named _Listing.txt.